# Alberti rank-one theorem and reduction of the study of BV function to the two-dimensional case

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

By [Alberti rank-one theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315401/meaning-of-alberti-rank-one-theorem), could it be possible to reduce the study of a function $u \in BV(\mathbb{R}^N, \mathbb{R}^N)$ to the study of a function $\tilde{u} \in BV(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^2)$? At least as far as the derivative is concerned?

Comment: You should be more specific about what you mean by "reduction".

Comment: @Bazin I don't know precisely, I'd like to know about anything that can be done. I was thinking maybe one  direction given by the "singular one" given by Alberti rank one and the other one  $\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$  the orthogonal.

Comment: As written in my answer on Mathoverflow, taking a $$ vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ with absolutely continuous divergence amounts essentially to deal with $=\sum_{1≤≤n}_j(′,_n)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ where $′\in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ and $\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_n}$ Radon measure whereas all other entries of $$ are absolutely continuous. Although it is not sufficient, it means that a good idea is to start with $_1(_1,_2)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$ in  $\mathbb R^2.$