# Heuristic and graphic representation of BV functions and their singularities

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

This question is about some heuristics and graphs of BV functions.

---

In **1-dimensional setting**, two key examples of $BV$ functions $u: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are

- the [**Heaviside function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05duc.png), whose derivative is the Dirac delta concentrated at $0$. It is an example of $BV$ function such that $Du = D^{jump}u$.
- the [**Cantor function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhrSW.png), whose derivative is the Hausdorff measure $\log_2 3$ restricted to the Cantor set. It is an example of BV function such that $Du = D^{cantor}u$.

The graphs of these functions and an intuition on the structure of their derivatives are quite straightforward. And actually, virtually all examples of BV functions I've seen in textbooks are 1-dimensional.

---

However, in the multi-dimensional setting I'm having some difficulties forming an intuition on these matters.

My **question** has a numerical component and a theoretical component.

- I'd like to see two nice explicit examples of functions $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which are $BV$ and have respectively $Du=D^{jump}u$ and $Du=D^{cantor}u$.
- using computer software like Mathematica or Matlab, I'd like to see the graph of such functions and a plot of their derivatives (so as to also see what the function at the  jump set looks like  the heuristic meaning of Alberti rank-one theorem on the "direction" of singularities, discussed in two other questions that appeared on MathOverflow [Meaning of Alberti rank-one theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315401/meaning-of-alberti-rank-one-theorem) and [Alberti rank one theorem and a blow-up argument](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328189/alberti-rank-one-theorem-and-a-blow-up-argument)). I'd also be interested in seeing a representation of the level sets of $u$.