# Is there a function $u \in BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $Du$ is an $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to the Koch curve?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Motivated by my previous question [Alberti rank-one theorem and irregular jump discontinuities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328790/alberti-rank-one-theorem-and-irregular-jump-discontinuities), I'd like to ask the following:

> Is there a function $u \in BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $Du$ is an $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure restricted to the Koch curve?

In particular, consider the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and the Koch curve  with end points $\{0,1\}$.

Does the characteristic function of the part of the square below the curve  satisfy the requirements of the question?

Comment: Is $s$ the Hausdorff dimension of the Koch curve ($s={\log4\over\log3}$) ?

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes.

Comment: Since $Du$ is zero outside of the Koch curve, $u$ should be an indicator of the set $E$ whose boundary is the Koch curve. Then $u\in BV$ iff $E$ has finite perimeter, which does not hold since $s>1$.

Comment: @Skeeve That's right and very unfortunate because it makes the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328779/concrete-example-of-bv-function-u-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr-with-singular-de, which that motivates this one much harder for me.

Comment: @Skeeve On the other hand, is the characteristic function of the undergraph of the koch curve BV?

Comment: What do you mean by undergraph? The Koch curve is not a graph of any function, but the set $E$ confined by the Koch curve does not have finite perimeter hence $\chi_E\notin BV$.

Comment: @Skeeve I meant the curve (https://fractalfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/kochprog440.jpg) not the snowflake, but now I see that your remark applies either way. Thank you.

Comment: @Skeeve In the spirit of this question (and related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328779/concrete-example-of-bv-function-u-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr-with-singular-de), I have a follow-up: Is it fair to say that if $u:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a BV function then $D^{cantor}u$ must be concentrated on a $1$-dimensional Cantor set?

Comment: I think no. The point is that BV functions can be quite different from the indicators (of sets with finite perimeter). E.g. in dimension one the only sets with finite perimeter are finite disjoint unions of intervals, however if we take the Cantor function its derivative is concentrated on the Cantor set (which is far from being finite).

Comment: @Skeeve I see. Although it is baffling to me that I cannot find a single example of function $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which is $BV$ and has Cantor derivative. Infact, I even wonder if $u(x_1,x_2) = \mathrm{Cantor Staircase}(x_1)$ ($(x_1,x_2) \in [0,1]^2)$ is $BV$ with derivative hausdorff measure restricted to Cantor set $\times [0,1]$