# Alberti rank-one theorem and irregular jump discontinuities

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Is it fair to say that [Alberti rank one theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315401/meaning-of-alberti-rank-one-theorem) means that a BV functions $u \in BV(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has $Du = D^{cantor}u$ if and only if it has a **jump discontinuity across a curve** that is not smooth (as it would be in the case $Du = D^{jump} u$) but **of "fractal type"** (for example **Koch** curve)? Or maybe many jump discontinuities across Koch-type curves oriented in the same direction?

If this is the case, how can one make this intuition rigorous?

---

Related questions are asked in [Heuristic and graphic representation of BV functions and their singularities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328493/heuristic-and-graphic-representation-of-bv-functions-and-their-singularities)  and [Concrete example of BV function $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with singular derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328779/concrete-example-of-bv-function-u-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr-with-singular-de?noredirect=1&lq=1).